# React js error in a simple function that takes an array and returns a random value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting an error that I am not able to figure, its about a function that takes an array and returns a random value from it. I used the same function last time and there was no such error

helpers.js

```
function choice(arr) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return arr[randomIndex];
}

export { choice };
```

box.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {choice} from './helpers';
 import './Box.css'

class Box extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        allColors: ["purple", "magenta", "violet", "pink"]
    };
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {color: choice(this.props.allcolors)};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(){

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Box" style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}
            } onClick={this.handleClick}>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Box;
```

here is the error
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to call your function in componentDidMount?

Comment: No, I am a beginner and dont know much about lifecycle methods. I was just following a tutorial and double checked the code many times, yet in tutorial it works but not in mine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. `this.props.allcolors` is `undefined`, because you have set the prop `allColors` with uppercase "C"
2. This might not be a problem in your specific scenario, but in general, the function `choice`, won't give you your desired result. It now only works correctly for arrays of length 3. To fix this, you could change `3` into `arr.length` like so:

```
function choice(arr) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: That happens from time to time... you're welcome! You could mark this answer as accepted if you like :)